# What is optimum query to calculate difference between two rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**Context:**
Data is loaded in table every 5 minutes. Each row of data represents a given department with number of calls received *so far for the last 30 minutes* i.e. a running count that resets every 30 minutes.

**Problem:**
Need to a query that will show running count for last 15 minutes.

**Hint:**
We can get a running count for last 15 minutes if we can show how many calls were actually received in each 5 minute load. We get that "actual" count by subtracting the previous interval (row) with the new incoming interval (row).

**My question:**
What is best way to solve this that will be the fastest in terms of execution? We are at the initial design stage, so this means we can either work from one table, or work with two separate tables (one for previous, and one for new).

Ultimately the result (difference) needs to be inserted in a different table.

Comment: "What is best way to solve this that will be the fastest in terms of execution?" Make sure you have the correct Index(es)...   "so this means we can either work from one table, or work with two separate tables (one for previous, and one for new)."   keep it as one table much more easy to query

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Thank you, that helps.